# API level specific layouts in Mono for Android

Tags: android, mono

I would like to use features of API level 11 if available in one of my XML-files within the layout folder. Therefore, I have the folder structure

layout 
-- myview.xml

layout-v11 
-- myview.xml

where layout/myview.xml contains (within a LinearLayout) a simple

```
<TextView 
           android:id="@+id/value" 
           style="@style/MyStyle" />
```

whereas for API Level >= 11 I would like to add the textIsSelectable attribute in layout-v11/myview.xml:

```
<TextView 
           android:id="@+id/value" 
           android:textIsSelectable="true" 
           style="@style/MyStyle" />
```

However, during the build with Target platform set to API Level 8 in MonoDevelop, I get `Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textIsSelectable' in package 'android'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use targetSDKVersion(>=11) and minSDKVersion=8 tags in your manifest file to resolve this error.

Comment: Because if you are setting TargetSDK with API level 8 then your app will not be able know features beyond that API level.

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="10", android:targetSdkVersion="17", still an error regardless of what folder the layout resides in.